# jquery autocomplete does not respond to dynamically inserted element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

We are working on autocomplete with dynamically inserted elements with jquery (did autocomplete on static elements before). Here is the html source code for one autocomplete added element inserted (there may be more than one element inserted on the same page). The id of inserted element is unknown until it has been inserted. The ids vary from element to element:

```
<input type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter keyword" name="requisition[material_items_attributes][1414037215952][item_name_autocomplete]" id="requisition_material_items_attributes_1414037215952_item_name_autocomplete" data-autocomplete-source="/whs/items/autocomplete" class="string required span5">
```

Here is the js code for autocomplete:

```
$(function() {
   $("[id^='requisition_material_items_attributes_'][id$='_item_name_autocomplete']").each(function (){
      return $(this).autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: $(this).data('autocomplete-source'),
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        }
      });
    });
});
```

When keyword entered in text box of `item_name_autocomplete`, nothing happens. We found that the js code for autocomplete was not executed and there is no match of the id. What could cause the no match? Is it because the dynamic element needs reloading before match (not sure how to use .on here. or there is some other ways to do the reloading)?

Comment: when you add new elements you need to initialize the plugin for the new elements after they are inserted in dom

Comment: @@charlietfl, can you provide more detail?

Comment: fairly simple, your initialization of the plugin only fires on page load and will only be bound to elements that exist at that time. In your insertion code of new elements find the new inputs and run the `autocomplete` method on them

Comment: Somehow our code can not find the match. The id of the inserted element is unknown until it has been inserted. The digits in the id varies from element to element inserted.

Comment: use a class and don't worry about ID. Show the code that does insertion

Comment: Is there anyway to call `.autocomplete({ ... })` again at the point of time that you add the new elements.  You are adding the elements with new inputs with javascript right?

Comment: We probably can not call .autocomplete when inserting. The dynamic elements are inserted as Rails (3.2) partial form. The id for the element was updated (make it unique) with javascrit.

Comment: Then add the autocomplete initialization to the end of the code that's updating the inserted element to make it unique.

Comment: Any examples we can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout solves the problem:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
  $("[id^='requisition_material_items_attributes_'][id$='_item_name_autocomplete']").each(function (){
        $(this).autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: $(this).data('autocomplete-source'),
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        }
      });
    });
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the onload code in a function, so when you create new content, you fire the function onload again...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function returnAccess(){
//all your code when the page load
//all the code you need to run like events or something else...
}
function createContent(){
//code that create content
//then you run returnAccess() again
returnAccess();
}
returnAccess();
});
```

so when you create new content, you fire returnAccess() again...
even you can put your function createContent inside return access if the new content execute too the create content...

Comment: We test the solution and somehow the autocomplete did not kick in after keyword.